# Recommendation on building web services on Linux with minimal dependencies

Tags: linux, web-services, native, daemon

I need a recommendation for a framework/library for building web services on a Linux system. I have the following requirements:

- It should have minimal dependencies, e.g. preferably not require any VM like Java or Mono.
- My service implementation should have access to the native system APIs, preferably it should be possible to call C APIs directly.
- If possible, the solution should not depend on a large web server installation. As I understand, Axis/C++ would require an Apache server, right? Is there anything that allows for writing some kind of "self-hosted" web service like in .NET (`ServiceHost`) on Linux? I would really like something that works as a standalone daemon in the end.
- The resulting services should be standard-compliant as I need to make cross-platform calls. Most importantly, I need WS-Security.
- The solution must be Open Source, the actual licence is less important.

If you have any suggestions, please post (web links would be nice ;-))

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

What about Twisted? http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/